# Probability With Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, probability

I have an array that contains the probability of different choices. For example:

Array 1 has {5, 3, 2, 7, 1} values. Choice "0" has a 5/18 chance of being chosen, Choice "1" has 3/18 chance.. and so on. "18" is the sum of the values of the array.

Here is my code (in this case we have 8 choices):

```
int i = rand() % sumofvaluesofarray; //edited from array_size
int c = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(c < 8){
    sum += array[c]；
    if(i < sum){
        choice = c;
        break;
    }
    c += 1;
}
```

This is all part of a non-working program, however I suspect the problem lies on this part of the code. Is there anything wrong with it? And is there anyway of writing this code more efficiently?

Comment: "the problem lies on this part of the code". what problem?

Comment: Please do not keep editing the code. Make sure you have posted exactly the code you are compiling. What is the problem? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: I'm sorry for editing the code. I only edited the code because it didn't reflect the code that I actually compiled. I guess you can call it typos. I changed the variable names of my actual code before posting it here for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The asker keeps changing their code. Note to future question askers: please post your code exactly as you are compiling it.*

<s>Seems like you have a couple of problems. Firstly, you should be creating a random number up to `18`, not to the size of the array:</s>

```
int i = rand() % 18;
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily give you `i` according to a uniform distribution (it only will if `RAND_MAX` is a multiple of 18).

In addition, you are looping `c` up to 8, when instead it should be 5:

```
while(c < 5){
```

Otherwise you are accessing outside the bounds of `array`.

You also have a FULLWIDTH SEMICOLON unicode character (U+FF1B) in this line:

```
sum += array[c]；
//             ^
```

Did you copy it from a document, maybe? Make sure it's a normal SEMICOLON character (U+003B).

If you're using a C++11 compiler, you can stop caring about how to write this efficiently and just make use of the `<random>` header:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<> d(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

With this, you can generate random values according to the discrete distribution by calling `d(gen)`.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect on what you pointed out. I'm looking "c" up to 8 because this time we have 8 choices, thus array[0]-array[7] contains the probability numbers for my 8 choices. Also I'm just starting to learn C++ and so I'm not familiar with your 2nd suggestion, especially the formatting.

Comment: @user2280704 So what's the problem? You haven't yet told us. If you get an error, please tell us what it is. If it doesn't behave how you expect, please tell us what it is doing.

Comment: My problem is that I'm having trouble debugging my program. This code is just a small part of my program, and I was wondering if there's something wrong with this code. Basically my main problem is I'm not sure how to implement the probability concept on my program, and I'm asking clarification if I'm doing it right.

Comment: @user2280704 Well does it work? Have you tried generating many random numbers and counting how many you get of each? See if it matches your distribution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was kind of lost on how to debug this program. It exactly matched the distribution after 10000 numbers. Thank you.

Comment: @user2280704 Just to add to what sftrabbit said, if you don't have a C++11 compiler, you should consider using `boost::random` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = rand() % size_array;
int c = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(c < 8){
    sum += array[c];    // Missing semicolon
    if(i < sum){
    choice = c;
    break;
    }
    c += 1;
}
```

You missed a semicolon there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if an algorithm in your code is working correctly write it in a function and create [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) for it. This way you can feed the function a predetermined set of parameters that can be compared against an expected result. Now when you go into a debugging session you can do so with the reasonable assumption that the function works properly and you can then concentrate on other areas of your code.

Comment: Yes I did just that and found out that this part of my program is working. Thank you.